# Insert inside the VirtuleBox

Tags: mininet

I have mininet VM on my virtuleBox. I downloaded from GitHub topology.py.

How can I insert this file in the path for that already installed on VM?

```
mininet@mininet-vm:~/mininet/mininet$
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is your question?

Comment: hi , i downloaded  topology.py and i want to using it .. I used the  mininet VM that installed in VirtuleBox .. So how i can import topology.py inside the Mininet VM .. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you need to move a file into the VM, try [scp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) `scp topology.py user@vm_ip_address:/path`. I'm not familiar with mininet at all, but it [looks like](http://mininet.org/sample-workflow/) it's in the system already and you manipulate it with `mn --topo`.